# Can I display the GameCenter leader boards for the player to choose from?

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center, gamekit

I'm making a game and it has 3 leader boards which all work and the scores are displayed ok. I have a button that when pressed displays the leader board using the code below.

```
    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
if (leaderboardController != NULL)
{
    leaderboardController.category = self.easyLeaderBoard;
    leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeWeek;
    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];

}
```

This code just loads the Easy leaderboard, is it possible to load the list of 3 leaderboards instead of loading a specific leaderboard? Which the user can then select which leaderboard they want.

Comment: Why don't you create 3 buttons instead of one, naming the 3 leaderboards? Or even a `tableView`.

Comment: Thats what I have at the moment, three buttons for each of the leaderbaords but I was wondering if it could be done with one button.